# Touchpad not working after installing UBUNTU 13.04 on HP sleekbook

Tags: touchpad

I installed UBUNTU 13.04 alongside Windows 8 on HP sleekbook. But The touchpad isn't working. I can open the terminal through keyboard and certain points are also sensitive to touchscreen. But the touch-pad doesn't work. Can anybody help me out???

Answer (score 0):

I also have an HP sleekbook, but with Ubuntu 14.04 and the touchpad can be used (though its configuration takes time). Perhaps you should first boot Windows, make sure the touchpad is active and reboot Ubuntu. Then try to type in a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

```
synclient -l | grep TouchPadOff".
```

If the result is:

```
TouchpadOff             = 1
```

type

```
synclient TouchPadOff=0
```

and try moving the cursor with the touchpad.